# Degree of a conjugacy class in an algebraic group?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a classical group over a field $K$ ($G=\textrm{SL}_n, \textrm{SO}_n, \textrm{Sp}_n$). Consider $G$ as embedded within the affine space $M_n\sim \mathbb{A}^{n^2}$ of $n$-by-$n$ matrices. Let $g$ be a regular semisimple element of $G(K)$.

What is the degree of $\textrm{Cl}(g)$, considered as a variety?

(For $G=\textrm{SL}_n$, it is just $n!$, since the conjugacy class of a regular semisimple element is just given by its eigenvalues (all distinct), and those give and are given by the characteristic polynomial. Is that true in general? I think there's something I'd be leaving out here.)

Since $\textrm{SO}_n$ and $\textrm{Sp}_n$ are of high degree ($\gg e^{c n^2}$) themselves, it would also be interesting to know whether one can express $\textrm{Cl}(g)$ as the intersection of $G$ and a variety of relatively low degree.

Comment: is the degree same as the dimension?

Comment: What? No, the degree as an algebraic variety. The number of points of intersection with a generic affine hyperplane of codimension equal to the dimension of $\textrm{Cl}(g)$.

Comment: For SL(2), the degree is 2. The conditions are ad-bc=1 and a+d=constant. Use the second equation to eliminate one variable and we're left with a quadratic, hence degree 2.

Comment: Yes, right - for $\textrm{SL}_n$, the degree of $\textrm{Cl}(g)$ is $n!$. It is also true that $\textrm{Cl}(g)$ is the intersection of $\textrm{SL}_n$ and a variety of degree $(n-1)!$, which is what I was getting at.

Comment: As a guess, I would say ,for a general simple $G$, the degree of a generic Cl(g) in $G$  is the order the Weyl Group of $G$.